# CKEditor 4, ctrl+v clears style sheets, even with ACF off

Tags: php, css, ckeditor

Whenever I ctrl+v anything (text, image) into the editor, it strips any  css at the top of the source code; Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I have 'config.allowedContent = true;' set in my configuration file; I've flushed my cache and done a hard reset and I *know* it's processing the updated config, but no dice.

What in the world am I missing!

Comment: You don't happen to have `config.ForcePasteAsPlainText = true;` in your config, do you? Does it happen for all three paste buttons? Do you have any content processing thingamajigs other than ACF?

Comment: I didn't have ForcePasteAsPlainText defined at all, I've set it manually to false but I get the same behavior. It doesn't strip the <style> CSS when I use the UI's paste buttons, only when I use keyboard shortcuts.